# Google Developer Console: How to see all ratings in review list?

Tags: android, google-play, review, user-feedback

In Google Play Developer Console I currently can see only the user feedbacks which have reviews submitted along with the rating. But I cannot see the ones with only rating (no review).

I can see some of those through the Play Store itself (by clicking on ALL REVIEWS button within the app page). But that one does not show all submitted reviews, either.

So, is there any way to view all the feedbacks submitted by users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of reviews in developer console shows the rating if there is some specific feedback (in words) and not just a star rating. If not you can always look at the counts of ratings with different stars on top? not sure why you want it in the list?

The only reason i can think of for wanting this is to know who gave you how many stars in ratings. This apparently is not possible.

Comment: Yeah I guess that makes sense. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I need to see this because i want to know which version get which rating.For instance today i get 1 star without a review. And i want to know from which app version the rating come.

Comment: to add on to Murat, I'd like to see what devices were used to make those 1 star ratings. basically, they should be included in the console just like reviews.

Comment: I want to see star rating (without reviews) to reply user and ask for suggestion to improve the app.

Answer (score 9):

Ratings without text review can be seen through PlayStore on your phone. 
It's only visible from Google Play on a phone (not a tablet). And you will only see ratings given in your current locale. Go to your app page, expand ratings, don't order by date (Or else the un-commented ratings will not appear, I guess it's a bug), and start scrolling down.

Answer (score 4):

Use [gsutil](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) to see all ratings. Simply download all ratings as described, the related csv file will contain direct links to the reviews. You will be able to see details like user name, used device, app version, etc. - and you can reply to them!

UPDATE: Google is no longer exporting links to reviews with no comments, starting from November 3rd, 2015. No reason was provided.

Comment: It works, and you don't even have to use the gsutil, there is a direct link in the Developer Console to download the .csv file that contains links to individual reviews. Simply copy and paste a link in the browser, and the Developer Console will open with that particular comment on top and an option to reply to it. In rare cases, links can become invalid if the user has deleted their comment, in that case the dev console will open in default view with whatever top comments it normally displays.

Comment: This is the right answer.  However the CSV files are missing the OS version, which would be nice to narrow down issues, eg poor ratings on a specific version of Android might indicate an incompatibility.

Comment: Do you have a link to an article that says google no longer gives reviews without comments?